# pd.DataFrame(...) resulting in TypeError when a metaclass is defined before it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, metaclass

I've been playing around with metaclasses to try and get a good feel of them. A really simple (and pointless) one I came up with is the following:

```py
class MappingMeta(type, collections.abc.Mapping):
    def __setattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError("Can not set attributes of Mapping type")

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError("Can not directly instantiate Mapping type")

    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return getattr(self, value)

    def __iter__(self):
        return (k for k in vars(self) if not k.startswith("_"))

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self)


class Mapping(metaclass=MappingMeta):
    pass


class Test(Mapping):
    x = 1
    y = 2
```

The class works perfectly in isolation.

Now when I do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
class MappingMeta(type, collections.abc.Mapping):
    ... # same as above

class Mapping(metaclass=MappingMeta):
    pass


class Test(Mapping):
    x = 1
    y = 2

print(pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2]}))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metamapping.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2]}))
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 803, in __repr__
    self.to_string(
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 939, in to_string
    return fmt.DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_string(
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1031, in to_string
    string = string_formatter.to_string()
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/string.py", line 23, in to_string
    text = self._get_string_representation()
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/string.py", line 38, in _get_string_representation
    strcols = self._get_strcols()
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/string.py", line 29, in _get_strcols
    strcols = self.fmt.get_strcols()
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 519, in get_strcols
    strcols = self._get_strcols_without_index()
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 752, in _get_strcols_without_index
    if not is_list_like(self.header) and not self.header:
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 1033, in pandas._libs.lib.is_list_like
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 1038, in pandas._libs.lib.c_is_list_like
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 98, in __instancecheck__
    return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 102, in __subclasscheck__
    return _abc_subclasscheck(cls, subclass)
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 102, in __subclasscheck__
    return _abc_subclasscheck(cls, subclass)
  File "/Users/rnlondono/miniconda3/envs/p38/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 102, in __subclasscheck__
    return _abc_subclasscheck(cls, subclass)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

The strange thing is (at least for me) if I put another `print(pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2]}))` before the definition of the metaclass, the whole thing works. For some reason, it has to be a print...

```py
import pandas as pd
print(pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2]}))

class MappingMeta(type, collections.abc.Mapping):
    ... # same as above

class Mapping(metaclass=MappingMeta):
    pass


class Test(Mapping):
    x = 1
    y = 2

print(pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2]}))
```

So as a hacky solution I could definitely go with that...

Also when I remove the `collections.abc.Mapping` as a superclass of `MappingMeta` I do not get the error - but then I do not get the functionality that I'm looking for (essentially using `Test` as a dictionary)

I'm aware this is probably not the best use of metaclasses but I'm just curious if anyone has any idea on what is going on.

**EDIT**

Accepted response answers the question, but just to provide a bit of context as to *why* I used the collections.abc.Mapping class inside of a metaclass. The reason I wrote this like this was so that I could write classes like the following:

```
class Test(Mapping): 
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3

'x' in Test           # True
list(Test.items())    # [('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3)]
{**Test}              # {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

Though the accepted answer definitely answers the question, I decided ultimately to just implement the methods provided by `collections.abc.Mapping` to avoid any other potential conflicts

Comment: Can replicate this. Pandas seems to be calling __subclasses__ on type internally. If you call print() before you have derived from type, pandas is ignorant of this, because type doesn't yet have MappingMeta as a subclass. If you call print after, type now has a subclass of MappingMeta. If pandas is calling __subclasses__ recursively, perhaps your MappingMeta class needs to handle it? I don't know enough about Python multiple inheritance to know 
 which route to type.__subclasses__() is followed: directly via type(), or via collections.abc.Mapping. Perhaps the first panda's call is caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this may create more trouble than it solves, but if you don't plan to derive anything from MappingMeta, this seems to get around the problem (in that your code above runs).

```
class MappingMeta(type,collections.abc.Mapping):
    def __subclasses__(obj=None):
        return []
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that the abstract base class in `collections.abc` are **not** designed to be used as metaclasses.

Although it could be "thinkable" about, one would need to know *exactly* what is it he is doing: metaclasses are for templating the creation of classes themselves, and collections.abc are base *classes* - not metaclasses, providing a framework to implement common collection patterns with minimal amount of work.

So, what takes place is that apparently when instantiating an instance of `collections.abc.mapping`, Python machinery does some checking on all registered mapping types, and your quimera gets in the way, and make things break.

The clean solution is just implement whatever mapping methods you want on yur metaclass manually. Even if you get to work around this issue - like the answer by @DS_London does, the Mapping mixin implements a lot of methods and mechanisms that might conflict with the mechanisms neded by `type` itself - and you have no control over then. The error you got is one such example.

What collections.abc would give you for free are just  `__contains__, keys, items, values, get, __eq__, __ne__` - and you might not even  need all of those - so just implement whatever you want, and get done.

And the reason `Dataframe` does not break if instantiated before you define your metaclass is quite simple: before that, the collections.abc machinery for virtual-subclass checking is not yet poisoned by your metaclass.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I figured that it would come down to "this is not a really good idea so better to leave it". Indeed the only reason I wanted to use `collections.abc.Mapping` was to get those methods for free, but now I realize it would be best to use less magic and just implement those methods myself!

Comment: @user3645016 So, in a way it was a good thing your code broke early. Otherwise you could have been building in a raft of insidious gotcha's for later! FWIW I used to merrily multiply-inherit from C++ standard containers (which also should __not__ be inherited from), until I was taken to task for it here on SO ...

Comment: Yeah 100%... this was nothing mission critical though, just some isolated experiments thankfully. Any code review on this would hopefully ended up with: *"Just use a darn dictionary and K.I.S.S.!"*